# Accessing Json Array of objects in React-Native

Tags: json, react-native

I'm able to call parcels using map as list.parcels and the output comes like

```
{parcelId: "12"}
{parcelId: "14"}
{parcelId: "15"}
{parcelId: "16"}
{parcelId: "17"}
```

but i need to print only parcelId value, so to do that I tried list.parcels.parcelId and it shows undefined. I need help in printing the parcelId alone. Thanks in advance.

Json is as below:

```
{
      "id": "7",
      "type": "history",
      "title": "History Parcel Delivery",
      "sender": "Paul",
      "price": "635.50",
      "parcels": [
        {
          "parcelId": "12"
        },
        {
          "parcelId": "14"
        },
        {
          "parcelId": "15"
        },
        {
          "parcelId": "16"
        },
        {
          "parcelId": "17"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, list.parcels is an array you must use an index to reference an object within it. So to refer to the first item in the array you should use `list.parcels[0].parcelId`. This will print "12". So to print a specific parcelId use:

```
list.parcels[i].parcelId
```

where value of i is between 0 and one less than the length of the array

If you just need a list of the parcelId you can use

```
parcelIds = lists.parcels.map((parcel) => parcel.parcelId);
```

Comment: Thank you. That answered my question :-)

Comment: Now I got the answer like 1214151617, is there a way to print the number one by one so that i can set an icon to each parcel id.

Output like:
Parcel Id : 12 (Icon)
Parcel Id: 14 (Icon) and so on

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean but you can do something like `parcelIds = lists.parcels.map((parcel) => \`${parcel.parcelId} (Icon)\`);`

Comment: Thank you, Now the output  is ParcelID: 1214151617

I need out put like 
ParcelID : 12 

Parcel ID: 14

Parcel ID: 15 

Parcel ID: 16 

Parcel ID: 17

I mean printing values one after one and not continuously

Comment: To do that why don't you just use a for loop?

Comment: Thank you, yes, i was not sure how to do that in return statement. Will try that :)

Answer (score 0):

i know it to much late,but i hope its helpfull for others,How to Accessing Json Array of objects in React-Native

```
 {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
    }



var cardatafetch=[]
for (i in myObj.cars) {
  var dataa= myObj.cars[i];

//and for push the array data into array var,i declare it above the for loop you can declare any where 

 cardatafetch.push(dataa)

}
console.log(cardatafetch)
```